# Function is not callable @ python3

Tags: python, function

I am working through a homework assignment and I could use some help.  The name of my file is pgreper.py.

The overall goal is to make a python version of grep, it runs as the following:

$ cat input.txt | ./pgreper.py "the*"

I am required to make a debuging trace callable function, and I should call like the following:

```
@CodeTrace.trace()
def matchLine(self, line):
```

However Pycharm is telling me that 'Trace' is not callable.

I also get an error from my command line: NameError, name 'self' is not defined.

Could someone please help me to sort out my functions, and help me make them callable, apologies in advance this work in still in progress.

ps please ignore my comments, in the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import re
import time
import datetime
import inspect
import getopt


class Grepper(object):
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern

    @CodeTrace.Trace(self, line)
    def matchline(self):
        regex = re.compile(self.pattern)
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if regex.search(line):
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                #if option == -d print the following:
                (CodeTrace(line).Trace(line))
                print(locals().keys())
                print(str(self.pattern) + str(regex))


class CodeTrace(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line

    def Trace(self, line):
        #Creating Timestamp
        ts = time.time()
        ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f]')
        #Calling class and method
        stack = inspect.stack()
        the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__
        the_method = stack[1][0].f_code.co_name
        calling_the_class = (" {}.{}() ".format(str(the_class), the_method))
        #Any parameters passed to the method
        #parameters = str((Grepper.matchline(Grepper).keys()))
        #return_value = sys.argv[1]
        (locals().keys())
        #Writing trace
        sys.stderr.write(ts + calling_the_class + "\n")
        """parameters + return_value"""


def main():
    pattern = str(sys.argv[1])
    Grepper(pattern).matchline()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you're supposed to use `@CodeTrace.trace()`, why did you write `@CodeTrace.Trace(self, line)`?

Comment: Originally I did not have to use @CodeTrace.trace(), my new assignment requires it, and they asked that I use my old code and simply change it.  Although it does not appear simply to me haha